# How to use variable to display certain content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, gallery, append

When I click the href, I want to display the image and description from the target id. Can someone correct this code for me and show me how to do it right? Thank you very much!

HTML:

```html
    <div id="gallery"><img/></div>
    <a href="#panorak">Click me</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
var datas={
            "images":[{ "src":"gallery/panorak.jpg",
                        "title":"PANORAK",
                        "date":"28/10/2010 Web Design",
                        "description":"desc",
                        "id":"panorak",
                        }, 
                        {
                        "src":"gallery/kamoa.jpg",
                        "title":"kamoa",
                        "date":"28/10/2010 Web Design",
                        "description":"desc",
                        "id":"kamoa",
                        }, 
                    ]};
$(document).ready(function(){
    var gallery=$("#gallery")

    //****I don't know how to display it right at this point

    var list=$("<ul/>");
    gallery.append(list);
    datas.images.each(function(i,j){
        list.prepend($("<li/>").$("<img/>").attr("src",datas.images[i].src).load(function(){ }));
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Right now your code should dynamically add two images when the page is loading. You want to change it so that it's adding the images only when the link "Click me" is clicked?

Comment: exactly! Also I'd like to know how to add the other details into the prepend part. Like giving the li element an id. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5r6D/

Have a look at my jsfiddle link for all updates.
You had some structure in flow issues and javascript error.

I am adding all image in array using normal for loop. once loop is done, i wrap images with `<li>` and adding the list to the stage.

*Keep in mind that images will not be shown coz it is not on the jsfiddle server. Try it on your side.*

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/T5r6D/1/

So the new update does not hide the full container.

The anchor #tag [href] will be matched with the images title tag. So once clicked on a button it will hide the image that matches.

Comment: This is the thing I'm looking for, the problem is that I want to unhide only one of the images, not the whole containing div. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Maybe by asigning the id to the li element? Or is there a more efficient way? Thank you!

Comment: No need, i am busy updating my answer using the #tag to hide images :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var gallery=$("#gallery")

    //****I don't know how to display it right at this point    

    $('a').click(function(){
        var list=$("<ul/>");
        gallery.append(list);
        $.each(datas.images, function(i,j){
            var img = $("<img/>").attr("src",datas.images[i].src);
            list.prepend($("<li/>").append(img));
        });
    });
});
```

If you want to trigger events when something is clicked, you can use `click()` function. And I fixed `each()` function part. Check this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). And I split some code to improve readability.